# GStreamer Custom-Plugin and alsasink Unable to Detect Format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plugins, gstreamer, alsa

I'm developing a GStreamer plugin following the GStreamer Plugin Writer's Guide and using gst-element-maker from the gst-plugins-bad repository with the base class set to basetransform. As a starting point I have developed a plugin named MyFilter that simply passes the data along the chain. The plugin is working, but when I run gst-launch with the debug level set to 2, I get the following error:

> alsa gstalsa.c:124:gst_alsa_detect_formats: skipping non-int format.

I am executing the command:

> gst-launch --gst-debug-level=2 --gst-plugin-load=./src/libgstmyfilter.la filesrc location=./song.mp3 ! flump3dec  ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! myfilter ! alsasink

From the base class that was created by gst-element-maker I have removed calls to gst_pad_new_from_static_template() because the calls were returning errors reporting that the sink and source pad were already created, I have set the chain function using gst_pad_set_chain_function(), have implemented the function gst_myfilter_transform_caps(), and have added code to handle the GST_EVENT_NEWSEGMENT event. The STATIC_CAPS string I am using for source and sink are:

> "audio/x-raw-int, "
>   "rate = (int) { 16000, 32000, 44100, 48000 }, "
>   "channels = (int) [ 1, 2 ], "
>   "endianness = (int) BYTE_ORDER, "
>   "signed = (boolean) true, "
>   "width = (int) 16, "
>   "depth = (int) 16"

I return the caps from gst_myfilter_transform_caps() using gst_pad_get_fixed_caps_func(GST_BASE_TRANSFORM_SRC[[/SINK]]_PAD(trans)). The pad caps are set using the default code created by gst-element-maker in gst_myfilter_base_init() using:

> gst_element_class_add_pad_template(element_class, gst_static_pad_template_get(&gst_myfilter_sink_template));

Is there a problem with the GstBaseTransform class? I have another custom filter which does not use the GstBaseTransform class and does not have this problem. I am using GStreamer v0.10.36 with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I think it is all fine. Just add some code to manipulate the data (the easiest would to to multiply the values by a factor that comes from a property). That would tell ever better whether things work fine.

Comment: The identity core-plugin uses the GstBaseTransform object in the same way I am. I replaced myfilter with identity using gst-launch and I see the exact same errors. Maybe this is fixed in a newer version of GStreamer? I'm not looking into this any further.